# How signed messages are sent when using Ethereum Payment Channels

Tags: raiden, state-channels

So I've read [Ethereum Payment Channel in 50 Lines of Code](https://medium.com/@matthewdif/ethereum-payment-channel-in-50-lines-of-code-a94fad2704bc) and have the general gist of how the contract works.  But I don't understand how the signed messages are transmitted between Alice and Bob.  Communication isn't done through the blockchain, so via what medium are messages passed?

I'm presuming there is a clever ethereum way to send messages, rather than having to fall back on sending signed messages via email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the author of this post on Medium?

Answer (score 1):

Raiden relies on each party running a separate client (it's currently Python based).  These clients are linked to the user's Ethereum address at start-up. Each client maintains its own current token balances etc.

The main point is that these clients talk to each other over the network/Internet via their own protocol (default port 40001), and exchange events and balance-proofs between themselves by this means. No reason it couldn't be done via email or other mechanism, but the client makes all of this transparent.

Raiden uses a [smart contract](https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/blob/master/raiden/smart_contracts/EndpointRegistry.sol) to maintain mappings of Ethereum addresses to network locations, so your client knows where to find mine when you want to send me tokens. (It's more complicated than that - there is capability for network routing, but this is the essence.)